# Quick Access / Favorite / Recent sections disappeard in Windows 11 Explorer Home Folder

Tags: windows-11, user-interface, files-folders

I've stumbled into a little issue with my "Home" folder on Windows 11 recently.
I have lost the "recommended" section / split in the home folder.

It is looking like this :

[image: The new menu]

While it should be looking like this (with Quick Access / Favorite / Recent, highlighted) separated :

[image: Old menu]

I have tried changing options in the Options > Privacy menu, but the UI does not go back to normal.

Please help me, this thing is driving me crazy.

Comment: Did this happen after a Windows Update? Compare *Update History* on some of the machines *having* the changed interface with some of those that have *not* changed. MS frequently makes changes to the user interface.

Comment: An update may have had an effect on Explorer Patcher or like 3rd party Apps but no effect on native Windows 11 machines that I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Explorer:

Click on View (Menu Bar - I see it in your screenshot), then Show, then check (enable) Navigation Pane.

That will put back what you are looking for.

If settings do not resolve the issue, then try two things:

**A. Restore Explorer Defaults:**  Open Explorer, Menu Bar 3 dots (...) , options, Restore Defaults.

**B.  Try running DISM / SFC to repair.**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**C. Explorer Patcher** and other third party additions may cause issues.

**D. Repair Install** is the next step if everything else fails. Start with Keep Everything.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Navigation panel is already enabled. This option control the left side folder tree and does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Try running DISM /. SFC (answer amended).  Also try restoring Explorer Defaults.

Comment: Did all your bullet points,. The issue is still there.
What'ts driving me insane is that some of my users also have the issue, but not all of them.

Comment: You may need to try a Windows 11 Repair Install to correct the situation.  That is the next step.

Comment: Also make sure you are not using Explorer Patcher or like 3rd party additions

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Create a `.reg` file with the following contents:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
  "HubMode"=-

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_36354489\{f874310e-b6b7-47dc-bc84-b9e6b38f5903}]
  @="CLSID_MSGraphHomeFolder"
  ```
- Double-click the file and allow it to execute
- Logout and login.

For more information see the article
[Add or Remove Home in Navigation Pane of File Explorer in Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/add-or-remove-home-in-navigation-pane-of-file-explorer-in-windows-11.2449/).